# How can I make TypeScript aware that `classInstance.constructor` in JS will give access to the class' static methods and members?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following code works in plain JavaScript:

```
class Post {
  static table = "Posts"

  title = ""
}

const post = new Post()
console.log(post.constructor.table) // will log "Posts"
```

But for some reason, TypeScript does not seem to be aware that the constructor member of a class instance gives access to that class' static methods and members. TypeScript will insist that `post.constructor` is nothing more than the same function as `Object.constructor`.

[image: TypeScript saying post.constructor is just Object.constructor]

This is problematic in a project that I'm working on. So I wonder, is there a way to make TypeScript aware that `post.constructor.table` does actually exist?

I have found a way that works, but it is super ugly and I really hope there is another way.

```
import type { Class, Constructor, EmptyObject } from "type-fest"

// Here I'm overriding the constructor function on a class instance type,
// because in plain javascript it's also possible to access
// the constructor function from a class instance and then
// get access to all the class' static methods and members.
type OverrideConstructorToIncludeStatic<
    T,
    Static = EmptyObject,
    Arguments extends unknown[] = any[],
> = T & { constructor: Static & Constructor<T, Arguments> }

// This augmented Class type allows one to define
// expected static methods and members on classes.
type ClassWithStatic<
    T,
    Static = EmptyObject,
    ConstructorArguments extends unknown[] = any[],
> = Class<
    OverrideConstructorToIncludeStatic<T, Static, ConstructorArguments>,
    ConstructorArguments
> & Static

type HasTable = { table: string }
type ClassHasTable<T> = ClassWithStatic<T, HasTable>

function extend<T>(classType: Class<T> & HasTable): ClassHasTable<T> {
    return classType as ClassHasTable<T>
}

const Post = extend(class Post {
  static table = "Posts"

  title = ""
})

const post = new Post()
post.constructor.table // now TypeScript won't complain
```

So that works, but `const Post = extend(class Post { ... })` is so ugly. And moreover, I'm not the one who would need to write that. The consumers of my library would need to write that and I don't want to do that to anyone.

Is there any other way of doing this?

### Edit

Of course I'm using over-simplified examples here. In case you'd like to know the real use-case I'm asking this for, you can check out this playground: https://tsplay.dev/wXqeDN.

In short, I'm trying to see if I can figure out a way to (un)serialize class objects that adhere to a certain interface requiring static methods for the (un)serializing process. The end goal would be that I could serialize class objects in a backend and unserialize them in frontend code.

But I just realized that that might not be possible after all, because I would probably also need to serialize the `classRegister` `Map` you see in that playground. And I'm afraid that may prove to be impossible. Unless I'd use something like `eval`, but we all know how dangerous that is.

Comment: I don't *think* you're asking about why this happens, but for those curious, this is discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841), and if you were asking this I could explain in my answer.  It would be nice if static members were at least added, but there's no way to do this automatically. Could you explain more about why consumers of your library would need this?  There might be some workaround involves changing your library so that consumers would be happier, but without more of a use case it's hard to say.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for that link. I've been trying to improve my code using all the suggestions mentioned there, but unfortunately without any luck. You wanted to know the exact use-case I'm asking this for, well here it is: https://tsplay.dev/wXqeDN So basically I want to offer a way to (un)serialize class objects, in order to send them between server and browser. Although I just realized that I may also need to find a way to serialize my `classRegister` `Map` and maybe that'll turn out to be the final reason this can't be done anyway.

Comment: So, if you're in charge of the library, could you change it so that either the *instances* have the serialize/unserialize methods you care about, or that users call serialize with both the instance and the constructor?  I see in your playground link that you've thought of these workarounds and saying you can't or don't want to use them.  ...

Comment: ... But those workarounds have to be less awful than trying to tackle ms/TS#3841 directly.  As a user I'd rather have to deal with the slightly weird requirement that my class instances need to have an `unserialize(data)` method (`serialize()` is completely reasonable) than anything else I've seen here.

Comment: Yes I'm afraid that that is what I need to do. The reason I was hoping to avoid having serialize/unserialize as *instance* methods is because then they will clutter up the autocomplete suggestions of your IDE whenever you write `counter.`. But it seems that is simply inevitable and I will just have to accept that. But then still I'm afraid that my end-goal is unachievable, because I don't think I will be able to serialize `classRegister` in a way that it can be sent between a backend server and a frontend client.

Comment: You could use invalid identifier characters to suppress regular autocomplete, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND2KlW) perhaps?  But at this point I guess we've digressed far from the original question.  Do we want an answer to the question that essentially says there's no ergonomic way to do this and that most use cases would be better served by a different sort of workaround?  Or do we want to remove the question? Or edit it to be something else?

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected thanks to caTS's observation**

Since `constructor` properties are not available you have to do something more or less ugly.

Your code can be made more general by getting the static properties of any class.

A variant using type casting might be:

```ts
type ClassLike = { new(...args: readonly unknown[]): unknown }

type InstanceTypeWithConstructor<C extends ClassLike> = 
 {
    constructor: C
 }&
 InstanceType<C>;

class Post {
  static table = "Posts"

  title = ""
}

const post = new Post() as InstanceTypeWithConstructor<typeof Post>;

const consTable = post.constructor.table;
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq3Rdw)

The first version of my answer was erroneously removing `prototype` from the properties of `constructor` using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types)
-- [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NrXOVW)

Comment: I don't think `Static` and `Constructor` are necessary: https://tsplay.dev/NVbJGN

Comment: @CaTS right, thanks a lot - I'm editing it. I don't know why I got fixated on eliminating `prototype`